# Use ngxs actions to trigger ngx-translate

Tags: angular, internationalization, translation, ngrx, ngxs

I am trying to change the language of my application by using ngxs actions. The Actions uses TranslationService to call something like this.translate.use(action.lang);

Its working without any problem on app init. Means I use APP_INITIALIZER to trigger an action to set the language from a cookie value. Works fine.

The same action is triggered by a button. But you have to change between the language 2 times to see an affect.

Means: change from 'en' to 'de' nothing happens
change from 'de' to 'en' nothing
change from 'en' to 'de' you see the new language now

But all actions work properly. You can just output the value directly and everything works fine.

Is there any suggestion where I can look into. As far as people might know ngx-translate is quiet complex. I just cannot create an easy abstraction to show some code here to test.

As I mentioned the first dispatch of an action works fine. You can also see the proper value in the stored variable. Only changes will not trigger translate.use(lang) in the right way.

I also tried to just call it twice. I dispatched the action twice on click of button. And also I tried to call the translate.use(lang) twice. Also I tried to wrap it into an setTimeout to check if there is a problem related to asynchronous calls.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  providers: [TranslateService],
})
export class LanguageModule { }
```

And my Action looks like this:

```js
@Action(SetLanguageAction)
  setLanguage(
    ctx: StateContext<LanguageStateModel>,
    action: SetLanguageAction
  ) {
    // This modifies your state
    ctx.patchState({
      active: action.lang
    });
    this.translate.use(action.lang);
  }
```

I expect to change the language on clicking button same as it works without using actions.

Comment: Action handlers are invoked outside of the Angular zone. Wrap `translate.use` call into `this.ngZone.run(() => this.translate.use(action.lang))`. Don't forget to inject the facade class into your state `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}`

Comment: Thank you that totally fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1):

As my comment has helped you, I'm gonna leave it as an answer. It might be useful for someone else

---

Action handlers are invoked outside of the Angular zone. This is by design and controlled via "execution strategy". By default NGXS uses the `DispatchOutsideZoneNgxsExecutionStrategy`. It executes your code outside of the Angular zone via `runOutsideAngular` in the browser.

All you've got to do is to invoke the `translate.use` method inside the Angular's zone:

```js
this.ngZone.run(() => this.translate.use(action.lang));
```

Don't forget to inject the `NgZone` class.

---